# eclipse and SVN adding jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I'm trying to make modifications to the trunk found at https://wafle.svn.codeplex.com/svn SVN repository location. The way that I did this in Eclipse was that I used Subclipse, added a new repository location, then opened up the project and right clicked on the trunk. Then I clicked "checkout" and checked it out as a new Java project. Then I found the folder containing the source code that I want to change and recompile and I used Build Path->Make source folder. Next, I realized that I needed 190394994 jar files that were all in different places under the project's "Third Party" folder. So I used Build Path->Configure Build Path in Eclipse, then individually added each jar I needed through "Add External Jars".

My question is; did I do all of this right, and is there something I could have done more easily, such as import all the jars at once instead of individually clicking each?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing:  rajah9 is exactly correct - there is a .classpath file already.
You just got a little hung up on a really odd svn repo layout.  the java stuff is mixed in with the .net stuff.  Check out the trunk and then do a file > import... then select general > existing projects into workspace.  You'll want to select the Source/JNAWindowsAuthProvider/ folder.
There is already a .classpath that references the jars in the ThirdParty folder. (not quite 190 million)

Second thing:  when you added the jars as external jars, it makes an absolute path to the jar file.  you want to always avoid that, if you hit the add jars button it will be a relative path.

Comment: thank you so much. upvote for teaching me better habits, and answer for throwing in some eclipse knowledge as well. This is the downfall of being the lone programmer on my team. On the daily, I don't get tips like these. But I come to SO to make up for it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you are embellishing a little and didn't add 190 million jar files by hand. (Even at 1 jar click per second, you would be going nonstop for 2,200 days.) Incidentally, you can shift-click and choose many jars from the same directory.

The secret is in the .classpath file; that is where the build path is stored. Someone before you has probably created a fully-orbed .classpath file and stored it in SVN.

If you created this as a new Java project, it will begin with a very simple .classpath with the folder for your project's class files and the JRE. (Apparently, SVN does not overwrite it with the .classpath or you chose not to merge your local version with the one from SVN.)

Next time, you might want to overwrite your project's .classpath with that fully-orbed one on SVN. Refresh and look at the Build Path. They should be all there and in place.

Comment: thank you so much. upvote for teaching me better habits and making me a better programmer. :)

Comment: You're quite welcome, @KyleM. We've been down this road before and are happy to share the bumps & landmines.